How to fix "Master Unknown message type[] From[]" gazebo
I got a task to work with the gazebo.
Installed it on ubuntu 22.04.
sudo apt install gazebo libgazebo11 libgazebo-dev
Later I found the react application from git to work with gazebo.
This is code from it:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { SceneManager } from "gzweb";

function SceneManagerComponent() {
    const [wsUrl, setWsUrl] = useState("ws://localhost:11345");
    const [authKey, setAuthKey] = useState("");
    const sceneManagerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        connect();
    }, []);

    const connect = () => {
        sceneManagerRef.current = new SceneManager({
            websocketUrl: wsUrl,
            websocketKey: authKey,
            elementId: "container",
        });
        console.log("Connected");
    };

    const disconnect = () => {
        if (sceneManagerRef.current) {
            sceneManagerRef.current.disconnect();
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }
    };

    const resize = () => {
        if (sceneManagerRef.current) {
            sceneManagerRef.current.resize();
        }
    };

    const fog = () => {
        sceneManagerRef.current.scene.addFog(0xffffff, 0.05, true);
    };

    const snapshot = () => {
        sceneManagerRef.current.snapshot();
    };

    const resetView = () => {
        sceneManagerRef.current.resetView();
    };

    // Ensure disconnect on unmount
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => disconnect();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="container" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            {/* Add your JSX here */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default SceneManagerComponent;

When I try to run the application, it is in the gzserver console, which I run in this way:
gzserver --verbose. 

I get this error:

If I try to change the ip to a published address.
 const [wsUrl, setWsUrl] = useState("ws://192.168.110.134:11345");
Then I get this error:

